# Add all fields together or return to original sum

Tags: javascript, jquery, addition

So I have a multi-input form with some fields that need to be added and some subtracted and to total to and display in a list that is displayed via a class. For some reason my math is not working to display the total. Ideally I would like to have the initial vehicle price start off populated in the first input box already and being displayed in the list that shows the total price. Can someone see what I am doing wrong please.

HTML:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
              <!--Adjust Vehicle Cost -->
              <div class="form-group col-sm-6"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"</span>
                <label for="vehiclePrice">Vehicle Price</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="vehiclePrice" placeholder="Vehicle Price" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-sm-6"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"</span>
                <label for="estimatedTaxesAndFees">Estimated Taxes and Fees</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="estimatedTaxesAndFees" placeholder="Estimated Taxes and Fees" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">
              </div>
            </form>

              <h6>DOWN PAYMENT & TRADE-IN</h6>
              <hr>
              <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-6"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"</span>
                  <label for="downPayment">Down Payment</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="downPayment" placeholder="Down Payment" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-6"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro"</span>
                  <label for="manufacturerRebate">Manufacturer Rebate</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="manufacturerRebate" placeholder="Manufacturer Rebate" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-6"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"</span>
                  <label for="tradeInValue">Trade-In Value</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="tradeInValue" placeholder="tradeInValue" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-6"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"</span>
                  <label for="amtOwedOnTrade">Amt Owed on Trade</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="amtOwedOnTrade" placeholder="Amt Owed on Trade" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">
                </div>
              </form>

              <h6>PROTECT YOUR PURCHASE</h6>
              <hr>
              <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-6"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro"</span>
                  <label for="extendedWarranty">Extended Warranty</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="extendedWarranty" placeholder="Extended Warranty" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"></input>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-6"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro"</span>
                  <label for="gapInsurance">Gap Insurance</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="gapInsurance" placeholder="Gap Insurance" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-6"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro"</span>
                  <label for="serviceContract">Service Contract</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="serviceContract" placeholder="Service Contract" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">
                </div>
              </form>




  <ul>
            <li>$28,435</li><!--This always need to revert back if nothing is filled out-->
            <li>Total Financed Amount<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span></li>
            <li class="total"></li>
          </ul> 
  <ul>
                <li>5.30%</li>
                <li>APR for 72 Months<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span></li>
                 <li></li>
              </ul>
               <ul class="fltrt">
            <li>$461/mo</li>
            <li>Estimated Payment<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span></li>
             <li></li>
          </ul>
```

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
console.log( "ready!" );
//vehicle price
$('#vehiclePrice').keyup(function() {
    updateTotal();
});
//estimated taxes and fees
$('#estimatedTaxesAndFees').keyup(function() {
    updateTotal();
});
//down payment
$('#downPayment').keyup(function() {
    updateTotal();
});
//manufacturer rebate
$('#tradeInValue').keyup(function() {
    updateTotal();
});
//trade in value
$('#manufacturerRebate').keyup(function() {
    updateTotal();
}); 
//amt owed on trade
$('#amtOwedOnTrade').keyup(function() {
    updateTotal();
});  
//extended warranty
$('#extendedWarranty').keyup(function() {
    updateTotal();
}); 
//gap insurance
$('#gapInsurance').keyup(function() {
    updateTotal();
});
//service contract
$('#serviceContract').keyup(function() {
    updateTotal();
});

  var updateTotalAmtFinanced = function() {
    var input1 = parseInt($('#vehiclePrice').val());
    var input2 = parseInt($('#estimatedTaxesAndFees').val());
    var input3 = parseInt($('#downPayment').val());
    var input4 = parseInt($('#tradeInValue').val());
    var input5 = parseInt($('#manufacturerRebate').val());
    var input6 = parseInt($('#amtOwedOnTrade').val());
    var input7 = parseInt($('#extendedWarranty').val());
    var input8 = parseInt($('#gapInsurance').val());
    var input9 = parseInt($('#serviceContract').val());
        var max = 40000;
         var basePrice = 28445;
        var totalAmtFinanced = input1 + input2  - input3 + input4 + input5 + input6 + input7 + input8 + input9;

        if (totalAmtFinanced > max) {
            $('.total').text('The maximum is ' + max);
            $('.total1').val(40000);
        } else {
            $('.total').text(totalAmtFinanced);
            $('.total1').val(totalAmtFinanced);
        }
};
});
```

[The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pju47/3/)

Comment: For one thing, your function name doesn't match the function you're calling.

Comment: Where is the `updateTotal()` defined?

Comment: ha... That's what's messing it up. Thanks Jason

Comment: Another issue is you need to set some default values or something because as is, on the first call you're calling .val() on fields that are empty so you end up with NaN in your .total list item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using a single listener on body, and filtering via selector...

```
$("body").on("keyup", "#gapInsurance,#foo,#bar", function () {
    updateTotal();
});
```

Comment: There is also on "change" which is pretty awesome, it supports content change. sometimes it is useful when browsers autocomplete or user pasts a string the only listener fired is change and not blur/keyup/keydown